# How to tell AUCTeX to not indent an environment?

Tags: indentation, auctex

I'm using the `comment` package for the `comment` environment. This environment cannot be indented, just like the `verbatim` environment. How can I configure AUCTeX to not indent this environment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does adding `("comment" current-indentation)` to the `LaTeX-indent-environment-list` work?; see  https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Indenting.html

Comment: @RenéB.Christensen additionnally I find in my customization file that my custom verbatim environments are added to `LaTeX-verbatim-environments`. (but perhaps the OP does not care for verbatim like treatment of his `comment` environment)

Comment: I added `(add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments "comment")` and evaluated the command, but I still don't see any change in the AUCTeX behavior.

Comment: @Jeff - One approach could be: `(add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list '("comment" current-indentation))`.  You can put something like this in your `.emacs`: `(eval-after-load
    "latex"
  (progn
    (make-local-variable 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list)
    (add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list '("comment" current-indentation))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps explained [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20184/11143) worked for me. Specifically, I added the following to my `.emacs` file.

```
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments "pycode")
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list
        '("pycode" current-indentation))
```

More information is available under `(info "(auctex)Verbatim content")` and `(info "(auctex)Indenting")`.

After I did an `eval-region` on these lines, I had to reload the `.tex` file that I was working on in Emacs for them to take effect.